# query elasticsearch index does not return full string

Tags: elasticsearch

In ES index,  there is a field called highlight, and it is String field. An example is like this:

```
highlight
"[""first"",""second"",""third""]"
```

I used the query to search this index, and want to return field highlight. The query is:

```
{
  fields': ['highlight'], 
  '_source': False, 
  'query': {'bool': {'must': 
            [{'range': {'created_date': 
                         {'gte': '2023-01-01', 'lte': '2023-01-02'}
                       }
              }
            ]
            }
            }
}
```

However, the returned results only contains first item.
first.
I expect it return full content like this:
"[""first"",""second"",""third""]"

Any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a typo in my code,  when I extract field, I write:

```
        for key in item["fields"]:
            result_dict[key] = item["fields"][key][0]
```

It is the reason why it does not show all fields.